# Azure AD B2C concurrent access token request

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

**Why we need multiple token requests:**

We're using implicit flow for our SPA to get access tokens from Azure AD B2C to access APIs that are protected by the B2C. We need to access multiple APIs and those are all registered as different applications in B2C, hence different audience for each. Since they are all different audience, B2C doesn't support a single token request for multiple audiences, so we'd have to make multiple token requests.

**Background on B2C setup**

We support local account login, as well as *social login* which is using our other Azure AD identity provider. We're also using custom policies for our B2C (identity experience framework)

**The issue**

The issue happens for user using the Azure AD login *social login*. The user **has logged in** before.

When multiple requests are made, we noticed the following network trace in google chrome:

[image: Chrome network trace]
The trace above showing:

1. Line 1 & 2 are the token request to B2C *authorize* endpoint for 2 different api/scope/audience.
2. Line 3+4 & line 5+6, those are redirects to *login.windows.net* and *login.microsoftonline.com* both as 1 set for a particular api/scope/audience.
3. Line 7 & 8 are both the the response (id token) form post back to B2C. The line 7 returns a **bad request** response from the form post.

**The questions**

1. **Why the need to redirect back to *login.windows.net* or *login.microsoftonline.com*?** Since the user has logged in before, shouldn't he has a valid session and thus B2C can just return the token requested?
2. **Can B2C support concurrent token request (or login) from the same browser for *social login* identity?** We're suspecting this is due to the auth state that B2C expect from *social login* is only **one** and unique, so concurrent login causes this to override each other which then cause the other request to be invalid. There is no details at all on the bad request response. It just shows a blank page with "Bad request" text.

-- Update March 5th, 2019 --

After some tinkering on B2C custom policies, I've managed to suppress the redirects, after having logged in once, by changing the following:

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SM-SocialLogin">
          <DisplayName>Session Mananagement Provider</DisplayName>
          <!--Changed to this provider instead of ExternalLoginSSOSessionProvider-->
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.DefaultSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <PersistedClaims>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            ... removed for brevity ...
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdFromSession" DefaultValue="true"/>
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Changes made is to use default session provider.

Why the external session provider would not suppress re-authenticating though? The metadata `AlwaysFetchClaimsFromProvider` set to false would not suppress re-authenticating as well.

But going with this workaround cause us another problem which is asked in a separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54981693/3295988).

Comment: I think the redirect is needed to test the session (sessioncookies are only sent to pages served from that domain). The double redirect might be caused by the social component since it’s not a AzureAD login (not sure about that)

Comment: @eckes yes the redirect is needed to authenticate (acquire token) against Azure AD idp, but the problem is b2c is doing it all the time. I managed to tinker with b2c custom policies to store the Azure AD claims in the session cookie preventing it from redirecting, but another problem came up where a stringCollection claims (claims array) are serialized as the List.ToString() where it is impossible to get back the original values on deserializing.

Comment: can you make your update the answer to your own question? i almost missed it because when i initially read it i skimmed and was like "oh no baby, this is all wrong"... then i realized it was an update and that it worked for you. It worked for me! THanks!!