# Azure AD B2C Serialize StringCollection claim in the cookie

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following setup for my B2C custom policy:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SM-AAD">
      <DisplayName>Session Mananagement Provider</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.SSO.DefaultSSOSessionProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <PersistedClaims>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" />
      </PersistedClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectIdFromSession" DefaultValue="true"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Notice one of the persisted claim is of *StringCollection* `<PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groups" />` type. The original values are like:

```
"groups": ["guid1", "guid2", "guid3", ...]
```

All the claims are persisted fine in the session (cookie) except the *groups* claim. Instead of properly serializing/deserializing the values, on the next token request, we've gotten the following in the JWT instead:

```
"groups": ["System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"],
```

Is there a way to properly serialize *StringCollection* claim type?

Comment: Hi @Izzul Haziq. How are you setting the `groups` claim value?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett, the `groups` claim value is coming from external idp (Azure AD)

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: @JussiPalo did you encounter the same issue? I haven't been touching B2C work recently so I might be outdated on, probably, the recent changes/fixes. But for our solution last time, we had to implement a simple azure function endpoint to serialize and de-serialize the StringCollections claims stored in the session (cookie), by modifying the user journey in our custom policy

Comment: I did, but was able to solve it by following the sample at https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac, as in my case we were fetching the groups claim from REST endpoint (which gets the AD group data from the B2C tenant).

Comment: @JussiPalo did you manage to persist the groups claim in cookies? meaning if you were to make a token request while still signed in, you wouldn't need to go through B2C sign in again, but it'll return the token containing the previous groups claim. _this might be more relevant for SPA_